# What happens inside the black hole?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon, singularities, tidal-effect

I have learned that whenever an object gets inside a black hole, it traps the object and sucks it inside. After it had been swollen by a black hole, what would happen to the object inside it?

Comment: Look up "spaghettification"!

Comment: What do you meant by "spaghettification?

Comment: Look up the word. It was coined specifically to describe what happens to an object as it falls towards the singularity in a black hole. Also, "spaghettification" is only the classical description of the object's fate: we don't really know what happens to swallowed objects at all because we don't have a full theory of quantum gravity. Lookup the notion of "black hole firewall" for example.

Comment: There's lots of unknowns, but it's pretty likely that whatever falls inside a black hole, in addition to spaghettification, is that it crashes into whatever form of matter is inside the black hole.   Nobody knows what form that matter takes but whatever falls inside will spectacularly collide with that and become part of what's already inside.   Also, read about time inside a black hole if you want your head to hurt 
 http://curious.astro.cornell.edu/physics/89-the-universe/black-holes-and-quasars/theoretical-questions/455-what-happens-to-spacetime-inside-a-black-hole-intermediate

Comment: It's a lot like Las Vegas: What happens in the black hole stays in the black hole.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We cannot know for certain what happens to any object that crosses the event horizon of a black hole because that object cannot send back any information across the horizon. If we assume a spherical, non-rotating black hole, and that general relativity still holds inside the event horizon, then we can conclude that any object crossing the horizon must hit the singularity at the center of the black hole. This is because all slower-than-lightspeed worldlines inside the event horizon intersect the singularity. General relativity breaks down at the singularity itself, so we cannot use it probe any further into what might be happening there.

If you're thinking about tidal forces, they will rip apart any composite object before it reaches the singularity of any black hole-- so that what actually reaches the singularity is (presumably) a stream of fundamental particles that previously comprised the composite object.

Comment: So we don't know what will happen to the particles? aren't they suffering the tidal force (because I think they have a "size")?